# TCP Vs UDP for VPN

Tags: vpn, tcp, udp

What is the best protocol between UDP and TCPU for a VPN ?

Many VPN providers are using UDP because of the speed gain, but what if it's used to connect to an Infrastructure to access Databases or Virtual Machines ? Is the reliability of TCP more interesting in this use case ?

There is already a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970383/difference-between-tcp-and-udp) about the difference between these two protocols.

Detailed use case:

I'm creating an AWS VPN. It'll be used to allow employees to:

- connect to an RDS database (to run any kind of request, huge or small)
- SSH to EC2 instances running our soft (for example for maintenance stuff)
- SSH to other standalone EC2 instances

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: http://sites.inka.de/~W1011/devel/tcp-tcp.html

Comment: [To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)